# Android SQLite database being deleted on "SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase"

Tags: android, sqlite

I copy over a valid Android SQLite database from the apk to the databases folder on my AVD. I verify with the DDMS FileExplorer that it is there and the size is correct. When I call the following function to open it,

```
 mDb = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(mDatabase_path, null, 
SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READONLY);
```

The SQLite DB file is **deleted** and a SQLiteException, "Unable to open database" is thrown.

What could be deleting it if it exists before the line, then is gone after?

Ian

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My copy function was missing the first byte so corrupting the DB. Android will in that case delete the DB and try to recreate it.